# How to detect in javascript if a Smart Banner App is currently displayed?

Tags: ios, safari, smartbanner

I want to detect in Javascript if a Smart App banner is currently displayed. I already inspected the DOM but there is no evidence of the banner.

Comment: hey @Marco what solution you implemented for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old question, but maybe this will be useful to someone. I did this in a following way:

1. Detected iOS user-agent;
2. Used `window.matchMedia` to determine device type and orientation with media queries;
3. Checked `window.innerHeight`

After my experiments I have following experimental window.innerHeight values for different devices with banner shown. You can find them below:

- iPhone 6 Plus portrait: `544px`;
- iPhone 6 Plus landscape: `286px`;
- iPhone 6 portrait: `475px`;
- iPhone 6 landscape: `247px`;
- iPhone 5 & 5S portrait: `376px`;
- iPhone 5 & 5S landscape: `148px`;
- iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S, iPod Touch generations 1-4 portrait: `288px`;
- iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S, iPod Touch generations 1-4 landscape: `148px`.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

While the Smart App Banner doesn't show up in the DOM, it does decrease the available height of the browser window by 84 pixels ( that's the number I got with IOS7 + iPhone5 ).

I'm going to use this decrease in window.innerHeight to determine if the SmartBanner is displayed.

( I'll need to determine if the user has iPhone4 or iPhone5 )

Mobile Safari does have other bits that affect the window.innerHeight but at most the bottom menu ( share, etc. ) and the larger address bar at the top decrease available height by 69 pixels ( again that's what I got via the Safari Web Inspector ).

Comment: Thank you I came to this solution too.

Comment: How to check it, window.innerHeigth & screen.height shows different values even if Smart App Banner doesn't show up in the DOM

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jquery:

```
hasSmartBanner = window.innerHeight !== $(window).innerHeight();
```

Comment: I'm not using jquery. So, is there anyways to do that with vanilla-js? Thanks.

Comment: @tuanngocptn, 

`if(window.innerHeight === window.document.documentElement.clientHeight) { /* no app banner showing */ }`

Please note that this isn't consistent, some devices may show the app banner and not change the height. A method to hide the app banner is to use `window.scrollTo({ top: 200 });` (200 is a random number choice, you can change it) then immediately `window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });`. The app banner should detect the scroll event and hide itself.